# Property 'roles' does not exist on type 'User' in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, meteor

I am a newbie in Typescript. I have a project in meteor, react with typescript and javascript.

I have a button which can be visible if the current user is having admin role.
My code is,

```
{Meteor.user() && Meteor.user()?.roles && ["admin"].includes(Meteor?.user()?.roles) && 
    <Button onClick={handleClick}>Go to SMS Room</Button>
}
```

The viewer those who do not know `Meteor.user()`, It will return the object of current user.

I am getting error like
Property 'roles' does not exist on type 'User'

Can anyone tell me what to do and how to remove the error ?

Comment: show the `User` interface

Comment: probably interface `User` doesn't have `roles` property type

Comment: Meteor builtin doesn't have `roles` in User interface.

Comment: So what is the alertnative to do this

Answer (score 1):

The default Meteor `user` collection does not include roles. Version 2 of alanning:roles implemented roles that way, which is probably what you are using.

You will need to declare a type that has the roles attribute, and then Typescript will be happy with you.

You will probably need to get the user record into a (typed) variable, let's say it's `currentUser`, and then refer to `currentUser.roles` instead of `Meteor?.user()?.roles` in your if statement.